# Cannot convert text file to json

Tags: java, jackson

hello am new to jackson and am trying to convert a text file into JSON but am having problem with my text file I dont know in what format the details of text file should be below is my code

> ERROR : org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Unrecognized field "Employee" (Class test.Employee), not marked as ignorable
>        at [Source: C:\Users\Ashwin Utchanah\Desktop\BIOGRID\jsonInput.txt; line: 3, column: 2]

```
text file : {"Employee":{"EmpID":1234,"name":"assd","designation":”programmer”,"salary":25000}}
```

**Employee Class :**

```
public class Employee {

    private int empId;
    private String name;
    private String designation;
    private String department;
    private int salary;

    public String toString(){
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append("************************************");
        sb.append("\nempId: ").append(empId);
        sb.append("\nname: ").append(name);
        sb.append("\ndesignation: ").append(designation);
        sb.append("\ndepartment: ").append(department);
        sb.append("\nsalary: ").append(salary);
        sb.append("\n************************************");
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public int getEmpId() {
        return empId;
    }
    public void setEmpId(int empId) {
        this.empId = empId;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }
    public void setDesignation(String designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }
    public String getDepartment() {
        return department;
    }
    public void setDepartment(String department) {
        this.department = department;
    }
    public int getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(int salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }  
}
```

**Main Class :**

```
public class ObjectToJson {
    public  static void main(String [] args) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        try {
            File jsonInputFile = new File("C:\\Users\\Ashwin Utchanah\\Desktop\\BIOGRID\\jsonInput.txt");
            Employee emp = mapper.readValue(jsonInputFile, Employee.class);
            System.out.println(emp);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you're trying to convert into a concrete object is not a valid one.

You can easily test this using a JSON validator like JSON lint.

https://jsonlint.com/

The problem occurs from the top level `Employee` field. Changing your input file to:

```
 {
    "EmpID": 1234,
    "name": "assd",
    "designation": "programmer",
    "salary": 25000
 }
```

Should fix your problem.

Comment: actually my text file is like this 
empId 1017
name Nagesh Y
designation Manager
department Java2Novice
salary 30000

Comment: Unexpected character ('e' (code 101)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null') 

am getting this error now